# ui-router accessing the child directly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a nested view ui-router application, whenever I access the child with controller directly, the parent data is not filled (but is called, and I can see logs)
what is wrong?

```
.state('home.app', {
    url: '/apps/:package_name',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/components/apps/details/app_header.html',
    controller: 'AppController',
    controllerAs: 'appCtrl'
})

.state('home.app.details', {
    url: '/', templateUrl: 'app/components/apps/details/app.html'
})

.state('home.app.images', {
    url: '/images', templateUrl: 'app/components/apps/details/images.html',
    controller: 'ImagesController',
    controllerAs: 'imagesCtrl',
    resolve: {
        package_name: function($stateParams: IStateParamsService) {
            return $stateParams.package_name;
        }
    }
})
```

when I access the default child (details child) the parent loads and everything is ok (view is filled with data) but no luck with images, the AppController is being called but the view is not filled

if I'm not allowed to have such structure, what is my alternative? I have some shared data, and some specific data that should load on child states (tho I can load them all in parent controller but I guess that is not the way to go, since parent controller should not load submodels)